# UIEvent passed into -[UIView hitTest:]

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm overriding the `-hitTest:` method in a custom UIWebView subclass. The UIEvent that gets passed to this method always has an empty set of touches ( `[[event allTouches] count]` is == 0 ). Shouldn't there be touch information in the UIEvent object or is this a bug?

I've tried other UIVIew types (e.g. UIView, UIWindow) and see the same behavior so it's not restricted to UIWebView. This is for any version of the 2.* SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was never able to figure out why the UIEvent passed into hitTest:withEvent had an empty set of touches.

I did come up with a solution to my problem though. I was only concerned with single-taps so I'm not sure how applicable it might be to anyone else's situation. See my blog post at:
http://ryan-brubaker.blogspot.com/2009/01/iphone-sdk-uiwebview.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to implement a transparent view on top of it, and then delegate all events down to the UIWebView:

- http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8486052

has a bunch more information about how they got it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cory. I haven't had much luck with that approach although I will go back over that thread to see if I missed something.

Still wondering why the UIEvent passed into the hitTest method has an empty set of touches...